# Create a Realm in Websphere Application Server 8.5

Tags: security, tomcat, websphere-8

I am looking for a simple way to create a "realm" within WAS 8.5. I am specifically looking for something similar to the APACHE realm system in which a user, upon first access to a site, is presented with a javaScript username / password dialog and, if authenticated, is allowed to use the site. In Tomcat, this is accomplished by modifying the tomcat-users.xml file, adding a username, passowrd and role. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In WebSphere it is already built in, you just need to configure repository from where you want to take users e.g internal file based, or LDAP.
Than you need to enable `Application security` via `Global Security`.

Check this page for more details [Enabling security](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_csec2.html)

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps to implement basic authentication. http://itcareergrowth.com/blog/2018/02/25/configuring-basic-authentication-in-web-sphere-application-server/#.WpQiSOdMGUk